# jQuery checkbox list show items that contain data

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use a checkbox list as a filter to show and hide items with specific data attribute values.
for some reason I can't figure out or find an example of this. Of course should be some what easy.  More or less I want to show all elements that match the value of a checkbox, even multi-selected items. 
So in my example below. I want anything with green to show and then anything with orange to show. BUT I also one anything with green and orange on their element to show.

Any help is most appreciated.

Example:

My elements:

```
 <div id="myFilters">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="red" name="colorCheckbox">red</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" value="orange" name="colorCheckbox">orange</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="green" name="colorCheckbox">green</label>
  </div>

 <div data-type="red green"></div>
 <div data-type="red orange green"></div>
 <div data-type="red orange"></div>
```

My jQuery

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

   var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    $("div[data-type=" + inputValue).show();
     $('div:not([data-type=' + inputValue).hide();
  });
```

I have a JSFiddle with my current code.

https://jsfiddle.net/azm58kxf/1/

Comment: First off, you have typos in your data-type attribute selectors

Comment: Secondly, think about what you are doing.  Your click logic is only operating upon the value of the checkbox you clicked (which also has an unmentioned error because you are not checking to see if the checkbox is checked or not.  Just because it was clicked, does not mean it's checked).  You're only using a single value for the logic.  If you want to do logic using multiple values of the selected checkboxes, you have to find them.  So logically that's fairly straight forward.  On click, find the checkboxes that are checked.  Then use their values for your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On click, construct an array from every checked checkbox value. Then, iterate through the `data-type` divs and check to see if their `type` `includes` any of the strings in the array - if so, show the div, otherwise hide it:

```js
const $checkboxes = $('#myFilters input[type="checkbox"]')
$checkboxes.click(function() {
  const substringsToShow = $checkboxes.filter(':checked')
    .map((_, elm) => elm.value)
    .get();
  $('.datas').each(function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    const type = $this.data('type');
    if (substringsToShow.some(show => type.includes(show))) {
      $this.show();
    } else {
      $this.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.datas {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myFilters">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="red" name="colorCheckbox">red</label>

  <label><input type="checkbox" value="orange" name="colorCheckbox">orange</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="green" name="colorCheckbox">green</label>
</div>

<div class="datas" data-type="red green">redgreen</div>
<div class="datas" data-type="red orange green">redorangegreen</div>
<div class="datas" data-type="red orange">redorange</div>
```

Comment: Very nice. I like it.  If you don't mind, can you explain the  underscore as the first parameter of the .map() ?

Comment: In jQuery methods, the first parameter in many methods is the index of the current element you're iterating over, which is often useless, so a variable name of `_` is sometimes used to indicate that the variable isn't going to be used. (you could also use `this` instead of using the second parameter, but that requires a full-fledged `function`)

Comment: Vanilla JS methods aren't like that though - sensibly, with their array methods, the first parameter is the *item you're iterating over* (which one nearly always needs) rather than the index.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation.  I know jQuery fairly well, some more of the indepth things are still a little foreign to me.  Nice work this is awesome!  Thanks